# Lanterna 3. How can i get keypad inputs like enter or F1?

Tags: java

En lanterna, Cómo puedo leer entradas de teclado como Enter o F1? necesito poder escuchar la entrada de teclado en todo momento para tomar acciones, así como escuchar la tecla enter para leer el contenido del textbox.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    SpringApplication.run(LanternaApplication.class, args);

    TelnetTerminalServer server = new TelnetTerminalServer(2000, Charset.forName("utf8"));
    final TelnetTerminal telnetTerminal = server.acceptConnection();
    KeyStroke keyPressed = telnetTerminal.readInput();
    System.out.println("keyPressed: " + keyPressed.getKeyType());

    // Setup screen layers
    Screen screen = new TerminalScreen(telnetTerminal);
    screen.startScreen();

    // Create main panel to hold components
    Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
    mainPanel.setLayoutManager(new GridLayout(1));

    //input
    final TextBox tbox = new TextBox(new TerminalSize(40, 1));
    tbox.withBorder(Borders.singleLine());
    mainPanel.addComponent(tbox);

    //label
    mainPanel.addComponent(new Label("New Label"));

    // Create window to hold the panel
    BasicWindow window = new BasicWindow();
    window.setComponent(mainPanel);

    // Create gui and start gui
    MultiWindowTextGUI gui = new MultiWindowTextGUI(screen, new DefaultWindowManager(), new EmptySpace(TextColor.ANSI.DEFAULT));
    gui.addWindowAndWait(window);

}
```

Probé con un ciclo infinito pero es inalcanzable después de que la ventana queda en espera. gui.addWindowAndWait(window);

```
 while(true){
    // Read input
    KeyStroke keyPressed = telnetTerminal.readInput();

    // Check the input for the "tab" key
    if (keyPressed.getKeyType() == KeyType.F1){
        System.out.println("keyPressed: " + keyPressed.getKeyType());
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirando el código fuente de la clase TextBox tiene programado el comportamiento para ciertas teclas:

```
          case Enter:
            if(style == Style.SINGLE_LINE) {
                return Result.MOVE_FOCUS_NEXT;
            }
            String newLine = line.substring(caretPosition.getColumn());
            String oldLine = line.substring(0, caretPosition.getColumn());
            if(validated(newLine) && validated(oldLine)) {
                lines.set(caretPosition.getRow(), oldLine);
                lines.add(caretPosition.getRow() + 1, newLine);
                caretPosition = caretPosition.withColumn(0).withRelativeRow(1);
            }
          return Result.HANDLED;
```

Como puedes ver, aqui esta definiendo un comportamiento propio en funcion de las teclas a las que da soporte, es decir todo este framework tiene definidos comportamientos en sus componentes por algunas teclas.

Te recomiendo que mires la lista de componentes que ofrece y el directorio de ejemplos que tiene en el repo del proyecto [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna)

En ninguno de los ejemplos utiliza ningún listener por el cual puedas analizar el evento de pulsación de tecla y a partir de ese punto decidir tu que haces, al estilo *Swing*

Si esto que te ofrece no te vale, puedes extender esta clase y sobrecargar el método en cuestión para que trate las teclas que tu quieras, aunque no lo veo necesario.